# How to separate functions between .h and .c files

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am attempting to separate my function prototypes and the actual implementantions between .h and .c files to make it easier to see what functions I have.

my compiler, visual studio, has removed the curly green underline from under the function prototypes in the header files implying it is seeing the implementations in the .c file, but when I try to compile it I get 100+ errors all saying stuff like "`syntax error: missing ';' before '*'`" or "`syntax error: missing ')' before '*'`" or "`syntax error: missing '}' before '*'`" both in the .h and .c files. They are mostly pointing to the parameters in the prototypes, but I could not go trough all to know for sure.

Is there some other special way to do this?

I tried:

- Making them extern
- Changing guards to a name i know for sure isnt already used

I do not know what else I can try.

Comment: Make a small example .h and .c file that won't compile and post them in your question.  Surely the answer is in the code, we can't fix what we can't see.

Comment: Whichever error is listed first, fix that first and recompile, then fix the next.

Comment: Thanks, but I fixed it by myself. the problem was a typedef'd struct circular dependency

Comment: Read a good C programming book such as [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and a good C++ programming book such as [*Programming in C++*](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html)

Answer (score 1):

The *first* thing you could try is posting your code so we can see it :-)

However, the error `syntax error: missing ';' before ...` almost *always* shows up because you have an unknown type, as per the following:

```
int main() {
    NOTYPE *x;
    return 0;
}
```

Since you're moving function prototypes into a header, it *may* be that they're using types that still exist in the C file. Those type declarations *must* exist before use, or you will get that error.

That (function prototypes with unknown types) is not the *only* reason that error occurs but I can almost guarantee it'll be a similar issue, trying the use a type not yet declared.

---

As per other information posted here, you can also get this problem with circular dependencies, such as with:

```
typedef struct { TWO *two; } ONE; // don't know anything about TWO here.
typedef struct { ONE *one; } TWO;
```

If the dependency was only *one* way, then you could just ensure the order of the two definitions was correct. With a *circular* dependency, you have to introduce an incomplete definition (really a declaration) to allow it to work:

```
typedef struct TWO;                // declare that TWO exists.
typedef struct { TWO *two; } ONE;  // define ONE, we know TWO exists.
typedef struct { ONE *one; } TWO;  // define ONE, we know all about ONE.
```

Note that this only works if you declare a *pointer* to the incomplete type, you won't be able to do:

```
typedef struct TWO;
typedef struct { TWO two; } ONE;
```

because the definition of `ONE` requires a complete type.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the error.

The problem was that I had a circular dependency with 2 structures and I tried to fix it by defining them both before implementing them, but that obviously did not work.

this was my code:

```
typedef struct A;
typedef struct B;

typedef struct {
    B* blist;
}A;

typedef struct {
    A* a_parent;
}B;
```

The following stackoverflow answer helped me fix my errors:

[Resolve circular typedef dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888386/resolve-circular-typedef-dependency)

Comment: I'm guessing those two incomplete types at the top are the *fix* since, with those, the code is correct. In any case, you only need the `B` declaration, so you can successfully define `A`. The A definition/declaration already exists when you try to define `B`.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, as that is the reason I tried it in the first place, but until I used that SO answer, the 100+ errors persisted, so I dont know what to tell you.